# How to play background music and still do other function in python?

Tags: python

I'm using the playsound module to play *background_loop.mp3* file but i cant call other function or run the other part of the script untill it finish to play.

There is a way to call function and run the script while the music is playing?

Comment: Have you tried using `threading.Thread`?

Comment: yes, but i still cant do other stuff untill i finish to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) to achieve this.

```py
from threading import Thread

# Create a new thread
# The target is the function to run
# You can also pass arguments to the function
t = Thread(target=playsound.playsound, args=["background_loop.mp3"])

# Start the thread
t.start()

# You can run more code here, that will keep going even while the background music is playing.
```

Comment: I've just done a test but it still dont run the script:

`os.chdir("C:\DarkRoom")`

`def music():
    playsound.playsound("background_loop.mp3")`

`t = Thread(target=music())
t.start()`

`print("test")`

@Xiddoc

Comment: Don't actually call the function (in your example, you'd write `music` instead of `music()`). This is because `Thread` needs a reference to the function, not the output of the function. See my edited post.

Comment: One last question, can i play multiple sound in the same time with Thread? @Xiddoc

Comment: Of course! Just make another thread. For example, right after `t.start()` make a `t2 = Thread(  ...`